# How to merge vim commandline and statusline

Tags: vim, command-line, statusline

in vim, the command line always at the bottom.
and the above is statusline (if display).

status line could formated powerful. it's cool but wast a line.

so, here is my question:
can i merge the statusline to commandline (not use ruler):

- normal mode. display statusline
- command typing. replace with(or switch to) commandline and ruler display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without modifying Vim's source code.

Comment: What about neo-vim ?

Comment: @aemonge - Can't say. Haven't used it.